# Pug doesn't show local image

Tags: node.js, express, pug

i have a problem rendering images with pug
this my app structure

```
app
 /mail
   /assets
      /img
        /logo.png
/templates
  mailTemplate.pug
```

and here's the static route in my express.js

```
//static files
app.use('/email/images', express.static('app/mail/assets/img'));
```

and here's the pug file

```
  img(src="/email/images/logo.png" width="112" height="43" border="0" alt="" )
```

the image doesn't render in the template while i'm sure that the path is right

Comment: Your path is incorrect: `'app/assets/mail/img'` -> `'app/mail/assets/img'`.

Comment: actually no the path is correct , i mistyped it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes in your pug file image tag
written as:

```
img(src='plas.jpeg' alt='' style='height: 400px; width: 400px;')
```

this will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Images are defined in pug with the help of img tag. An example is given below:

//Name of the file : image.png

```
img(src='image.png')
```